# Correct way to instrument a Jersey client

Tags: jax-rs, jersey-2.0, jersey-client, aws-xray

My goal is to instrument a Jersey client to collect data on HTTP response/execution time, and I had thought I had the right approach by implementing a JAX-RS `ClientRequestFilter` and a `ClientResponseFilter` with code in each to record the start and end of the request. However when used with code like the following:

```java
InputStream is = client.target("https://mytarget")
  .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM).get(InputStream.class));
// Actually consume the stream, which seems to block waiting for data
final byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
```

... I experience a significant problem as I only end up measuring what appears to be time to header download, and do not measure time it takes to download the entire entity which seems to be happen as I convert the input stream to a byte array (just an example, in my case I am reading the entity contents as they become available).

My use case is to instrument it for use with a distributed tracer ([AWS X-Ray](https://aws.amazon.com/xray/)). An alternative I had considered was to use [a library for Apache HttpClient for this purpose](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-sdk-java-httpclients.html), but that would require [changing the default transport layer](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/client.html#d0e4971) for Jersey which seemed like an extreme modification to fix a simple problem. (This is slightly more straightforward with RESTEasy since it does appear to [use Apache HttpClient by default](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0-beta-3/userguide/html/RESTEasy_Client_Framework.html#transport_layer) so with RESTEasy I might have gone that route.)

Is it possible with Jersey to set up a filter that executes when the last byte is written to the entity? Or is there a better way to go about instrumenting a Jersey client?

Comment: Did you happen to find the solution for this ?